# Check if system function exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

Is there a way to retrieve all system functions (like `Binary_Checksum`) via query in SQL Server? Unfortunately these functions aren't in the `sys.objects`.

The purpose:
I want to create a procedure, that gets a function as parameter (among other parameters) to generate a Create/Alter Table query incl. a computed column. But before that I want to check if these function exists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you might be trying to do more than is useful inside SQL Server.

Comment: Aside, first thing that springs to mind is to exec a dynamic SQL string in a try/catch and parse `error_message()`

Comment: Such functions are part of the language's syntax proper; they're not exposed anywhere but the parser. Things like `BINARY_CHECKSUM` accept idiosyncratic syntax like `*` which is parsed specially (`SELECT WACKY_FUNC(1)` gives "not a built-in function name", but `SELECT WACKY_FUNC(*)` gives "incorrect syntax near '*'"). You can't do much more than attempt the statement and see if it fails.

Comment: @Stu I want to prevent that not existing functions break the query - I'll try your try/catch recommendation - thanks

Comment: The only time this would ever be an issue afaics is if you're porting code from a modern supported version back to SQL Server 2014, and even then only when using a function added since 2016 within a computed column. I've won the lottery more times.

Comment: _I've won the lottery more times._ Me too, but somehow the "wins" rarely pay the price of the lotto ticket. :)